# Moments.js рассчитывает время от перезапуска vs code

Tags: javascript, discord

При отправке сообщения в now попадает время, в момент запуска vs code, а не момента нажатия команды запроса

```
var today = new Date();
var now = moment(today, 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm');
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) {
      return;
   }

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) {
      return;
   }

   if (message.content === "!время") {
      message.reply("Время " + now ).then(() => {
         message.delete();
      })
   }
});
```

Comment: У вас под вопросом есть ссылка "Удалить", нажмите её.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он более не актуален, и автор сам хочет его удалить.

Comment: не делайте так! Ворос есть, если вы переосмыслили и считаете, что он бесполезен здесть нажмите "удалить" под самим вопросом. Но полностью изменять и писать, что это более не интересно вам - просто не уважение к участникам сообщества